# Getting error in @Wagmi/connectors package while using Angular, Viem, and Ethers libraries

Tags: angular, ethereum, wagmi

I'm working in a new project that uses Wagmi, Viem and Ethers libraries.
I installed the project without any problem. However, I've the following error in one the files of the @Wagmi/connectors package:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6BFH.png)

I've tried installing other versions of this package but I continue having the same issue.

This is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "demo",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^16.0.0",
    "@wagmi/core": "^1.0.5",
    "@web3modal/ethereum": "^2.4.1",
    "@web3modal/html": "^2.4.1",
    "ethers": "^5.7.2",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "viem": "^0.3.33",
    "zone.js": "~0.13.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^16.0.1",
    "@angular/cli": "~16.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^16.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.0",
    "@types/ws": "^8.5.4",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.6.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "typescript": "~5.0.2"
  }
}
```

I don't know what the problem is.

I tried to install other versions of these libraries but I couldn't fix it.